What is the intuition behind this sequence having limit 1/2?

I was working on this problem from an elementary real analysis textbook (from https://classicalrealanalysis.com/), and I had absolutely no intuition for why this limit is $1/2$. I noticed that $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+a_n^2}~$ for $n>1$, and I was able to show the limit of $a_n/n$ using induction, but I based my process of induction on the assumption that the limit was indeed $1/2$, and if this were not given, I would have no idea how to do this question.
I also considered generalizations of this question, noticing that the square root is the same as raising to the power of $1/2$, so perhaps the same question with cube root in place for the square root would have limit $1/3$? But when I tried this case with induction, it suggested that the limit is instead $0$ (I was able to show $a_n/n < 1/3 + 1/n$ but unable to show $a_n/n > 1/3 - 1/n$).
I then created a program to calculate the sequence numerically, and unless I made a mistake in my programming, I found that when raising to the power $1/c$, if $c>2$, the limit is $0$, and if $c\in(0,2)$, the limit diverges to infinity. (from the few negative cases I tested, the sequence seems to converge to $0$ by itself, without dividing by $n$).
So now I am even more confused, it seems like square root is "special" in that everything else either goes to $0$, or $\infty$. And is the limit from taking the square root (raising to the power of $1/2$) equalling $1/2$ just a coincidence?

How do you prove a limit by "induction" ?

I may have made a mistake, but I showed that $a_n/n < 1/2 + 1/n$ and $a_n/n > 1/2 - 1/n$ each with induction. I guess it would be more accurate to say I used induction to justify showing the limit by the squeeze theorem

What you did sounds like the correct procedure (in effect you found that for any $\epsilon$, $n>N=\frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies |a_n/n - 1/2| < \epsilon$). This procedure is not induction, where you would assume some statement $P_n$ and show $P_n$ directly implies $P_{n+1}$

By induction, I meant I did something like:
If $a_k/k < 1/2 + 1/k$ then $a_{k+1}/(k+1)<1/2+1/(k+1)$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$, I used induction as an argument to show that $a_n/n < 1/2 + 1/n$ was true, and similarly for the lower bound, and then the limit follows

I don't think that $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+a_n^2}$ can be correct... after all, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$, then your recursion gives $L=\sqrt{L+L^2}$. Squaring both sides gives $L^2=L+L^2$, which implies $L=0$

Sorry I probably should've made this more clear in the question, we are concerned with the $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$. In fact, $a_n$ itself diverges to infinity, I have updated the question.
$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+a_n^2}$ follows directly from the definition of the sequence,
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_1+\dots+a_n}=\sqrt{a_n^2+a_n}$$

Let's say we had a general sequence as you suggest with
$$a_{n+1} = \sqrt[r]{a_1+\cdots+a_n} = a_n\sqrt[r]{1+\frac{1}{a_n^{r-1}}}$$
For $a_1=1$, clearly the sequence is monotonically increasing, crucially with $a_n>1$ for $n>2$. For $r>1$, we can assume for large enough $n$ the sequence has grown enough for us to assume
$$a_{n+1} \approx a_n\left(1+\frac{1}{ra_n^{r-1}}\right) \implies a_{n+1}-a_n \approx \frac{1}{ra_n^{r-2}}$$
You can see the analogy to differential equations in this difference equation, where the growth of the sequence is either sublinear or superlinear. However at exactly $r=2$, we get that for large $n$
$$a_{n+1}-a_n \approx \frac{1}{2} \implies a_n = \frac{n}{2} + o(n)$$
This is the intuition behind why only the square root sequence converges to a linear limit and why that limit would be $\frac{1}{2}$

How do we approximate $$\sqrt[r]{1+\frac{1}{a_n^{r-1}}} \approx \left( 1 + \frac{1}{ra_n^{r-1}} \right)$$ is this a well-known result or am I simply missing something? (Admittedly I am not that knowledgable in maths). Also, how can we justify that the sequence grows large enough? It doesn't seem trivial to me that the sequence will grow indefinitely large

Actually, I have realized that you are assuming that $a_n$ has grown large enough, not $a_n / n$, but I am still wondering about the approximation

@chair it is simple Taylor series
